# NativeScript Monetization and Ads, AdMob plugin

Tags: google-play, admob, nativescript

I want to create a paid app with nativescript and keep it in "play store". But I want to allow to download my app as "free with ads" in it. Which option should I use? If I choose the paid version then it is not available to download so should I choose "pay in app" ?

https://play.google.com/about/monetization-ads/payments/

I intend to use NativeScript AdMob plugin to manage ads but how can I know that user has paid already and I should to not init my ads for him?

https://plugins.nativescript.rocks/plugin/nativescript-admob

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you are using [`nativescript-admob` plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-admob) alongside [`nativescript-purchase`](https://github.com/PeterStaev/nativescript-purchase). Then you could track when a product is **purchased** or **restored** and "remember" this via the `application-settings` module.

For example,

```
import {getBoolean, setBoolean } from "tns-core-modules/application-settings";

// ... more code follow here

if (transaction.transactionState === TransactionState.Purchased) {
   /* Purchase of the FULL  version */
   if (transaction.productIdentifier.indexOf(".full") >= 0) {
         setBoolean(transaction.productIdentifier, true);
   }
// ... more code follows here
```

Then, before opening an AdMob advertisement, check if the product is puchased via the `getBoolean`.

For example:

```
this.isPurchased = getBoolean(fullVersionPurchase); // fullVersionPurchase === transaction.productIdentifie
if (!this.isPurchased) {
   this.showBanner(); // where showBaneer is your AdMob functionality
}
```

And following the same logic, you could directly close the banner immediately after a successful purchase (or restore).

```
if (transaction.transactionState === TransactionState.Purchased) {

   if (transaction.productIdentifier.indexOf(".full") >= 0) {
      setBoolean(transaction.productIdentifier, true);
   }

    try {
        admob.hideBanner();
    } catch (err) { }
```

With the above approach,  you could create a free app that comes with AdMob and then when a user purchases the full version to immediately provide the full version functionalities. See [here](https://github.com/PeterStaev/nativescript-purchase#usage) for more details on the `nativescript-purchase` functionalities.